# How tp merge rows with same index with different values in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, columnsorting

I have a spreadsheet with an index called `uniqueStyle` and multiple columns. `uniqueStyle` has multiple `size` and `primaryImg-src`. I want to collapse the rows they have the same `uniqueStyle` with each size and img-src in its own cell.

Here is wan example of at I have:

```
uniqueStyle   dressTitle      size        imageSrc
CH1506        Lace Bodice Sateen Sheath Dress   
CH1506                              S   
CH1506                              M   
CH1506                              L   
CH1506                              XL  
CH1506                              2X  
CH1506                              3X  
CH1506                                              /image/1000x1500/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/c/h/ch1506_2_.jpg
CH1506                                              /image/1000x1500/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/c/h/ch1506.jpg
CH1506                                              /1/image/1000x1500/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/c/h/ch1506_3_.jpg
CH1506                                                  /1/image/1000x1500/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/c/h/ch1506_4_.jpg
```

The resulting output desired:

```
uniqueStyle         dressTitle                      size                imageSrc
CH1506              Lace Bodice S..                 S        /image/1000x1500/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/c/h/ch1506_2_.jpg
CH1506                                              M        /image/1000x1500/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/c/h/ch1506.jpg
CH1506                                              L        /1/image/1000x1500/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/c/h/ch1506_3_.jpg
CH1506                                              XL       /1/image/1000x1500/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/c/h/ch1506_4_.jpg
CH1506                                              2X  
CH1506                                              3X
```

(Sorry, couldn't get the text to align properly on here.)

Comment: @player0 https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1oK3VzWGSR5GWAw7gl0YdJkiqoMzG1K764rfhhI90MuI/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: do you need to preserve the order as in Column A?

Comment: @player0 No, as long as everything is there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with a few simple queries, you can preserve even order:

```
={Original!A1:F1; ARRAYFORMULA({ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(SORT(IF(ISERROR(VALUE(QUERY({
 QUERY(TO_TEXT(Original!A2:D), "order by Col1", 0),
 QUERY(TO_TEXT(Original!A2:E), "select Col5 order by Col1,Col5 desc", 0),
 QUERY(TO_TEXT(Original!A2:F), "select Col6 order by Col1,Col6 desc", 0)},
 "where Col5 is not null or Col6 is not null", 0))), (QUERY({
 QUERY(TO_TEXT(Original!A2:D), "order by Col1", 0), 
 QUERY(TO_TEXT(Original!A2:E), "select Col5 order by Col1,Col5 desc", 0),
 QUERY(TO_TEXT(Original!A2:F), "select Col6 order by Col1,Col6 desc", 0)},
 "where Col5 is not null or Col6 is not null", 0)), IF(QUERY({
 QUERY(TO_TEXT(Original!A2:D), "order by Col1", 0),
 QUERY(TO_TEXT(Original!A2:E), "select Col5 order by Col1,Col5 desc", 0),
 QUERY(TO_TEXT(Original!A2:F), "select Col6 order by Col1,Col6 desc", 0)},
 "where Col5 is not null or Col6 is not null", 0)<>"", VALUE(QUERY({
 QUERY(TO_TEXT(Original!A2:D), "order by Col1", 0),
 QUERY(TO_TEXT(Original!A2:E), "select Col5 order by Col1,Col5 desc", 0), 
 QUERY(TO_TEXT(Original!A2:F), "select Col6 order by Col1,Col6 desc", 0)},
 "where Col5 is not null or Col6 is not null", 0)), )), 1, 1), 999^99, 4),
 QUERY(TO_TEXT(SORT(IF(ISERROR(VALUE(QUERY({
 QUERY(TO_TEXT(Original!A2:D), "order by Col1", 0), 
 QUERY(TO_TEXT(Original!A2:E), "select Col5 order by Col1,Col5 desc", 0),
 QUERY(TO_TEXT(Original!A2:F), "select Col6 order by Col1,Col6 desc", 0)},
 "where Col5 is not null or Col6 is not null", 0))), (QUERY({
 QUERY(TO_TEXT(Original!A2:D), "order by Col1", 0), 
 QUERY(TO_TEXT(Original!A2:E), "select Col5 order by Col1,Col5 desc", 0),
 QUERY(TO_TEXT(Original!A2:F), "select Col6 order by Col1,Col6 desc", 0)},
 "where Col5 is not null or Col6 is not null", 0)), IF(QUERY({
 QUERY(TO_TEXT(Original!A2:D), "order by Col1", 0),
 QUERY(TO_TEXT(Original!A2:E), "select Col5 order by Col1,Col5 desc", 0),
 QUERY(TO_TEXT(Original!A2:F), "select Col6 order by Col1,Col6 desc", 0)},
 "where Col5 is not null or Col6 is not null", 0)<>"", VALUE(QUERY({
 QUERY(TO_TEXT(Original!A2:D), "order by Col1", 0),
 QUERY(TO_TEXT(Original!A2:E), "select Col5 order by Col1,Col5 desc", 0),
 QUERY(TO_TEXT(Original!A2:F), "select Col6 order by Col1,Col6 desc", 0)},
 "where Col5 is not null or Col6 is not null", 0)), )), 1, 1, 5, 1)), "select Col5", 0),
 QUERY(SORT(IF(ISERROR(VALUE(QUERY({
 QUERY(TO_TEXT(Original!A2:D), "order by Col1", 0),
 QUERY(TO_TEXT(Original!A2:E), "select Col5 order by Col1,Col5 desc", 0),
 QUERY(TO_TEXT(Original!A2:F), "select Col6 order by Col1,Col6 desc", 0)},
 "where Col5 is not null or Col6 is not null", 0))), (QUERY({
 QUERY(TO_TEXT(Original!A2:D), "order by Col1", 0), 
 QUERY(TO_TEXT(Original!A2:E), "select Col5 order by Col1,Col5 desc", 0),
 QUERY(TO_TEXT(Original!A2:F), "select Col6 order by Col1,Col6 desc", 0)},
 "where Col5 is not null or Col6 is not null", 0)), IF(QUERY({
 QUERY(TO_TEXT(Original!A2:D), "order by Col1", 0),
 QUERY(TO_TEXT(Original!A2:E), "select Col5 order by Col1,Col5 desc", 0),
 QUERY(TO_TEXT(Original!A2:F), "select Col6 order by Col1,Col6 desc", 0)},
 "where Col5 is not null or Col6 is not null", 0)<>"", VALUE(QUERY({
 QUERY(TO_TEXT(Original!A2:D), "order by Col1", 0), 
 QUERY(TO_TEXT(Original!A2:E), "select Col5 order by Col1,Col5 desc", 0),
 QUERY(TO_TEXT(Original!A2:F), "select Col6 order by Col1,Col6 desc", 0)},
 "where Col5 is not null or Col6 is not null", 0)), )), 1, 1), "select Col6", 0)})}
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Wow. That worked perfectly! One more questions, let's say I wanted to add another column named ```colors``` and ```colors``` needs to go with each size. For example: if I have sizes 1, 2, 3 and colors red and blue.

Comment: that means my table would need to look something like this: 

`uniqueID  Title                Size   Color  imgSrc
UR135     Beaded Short Dress   1      Red    https://...1.jpg
UR135                          2      Red    https://...2.jpg
UR135                          3      Red    https://...3.jpg
UR135                          1      Blue
UR135                          2      Blue
UR135                          3      Blue`

Comment: it depends on how exactly it looks like but it can be done for sure

Comment: How can I sort this list with the images in order? For example there's images that end in something xxxx_1_1.png and xxxx_1_2.png

Comment: with this formula, you can't. I added another solution which solves it

Answer (score 1):

if you don't need the order to be preserved take this:

```
={Original!A1:F1; ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY({ 
 QUERY(TO_TEXT(Original!A2:D), "order by Col1", 0),
 QUERY(TO_TEXT(Original!A2:E), "select Col5 order by Col1,Col5 desc", 0),
 QUERY(TO_TEXT(Original!A2:F), "select Col6 order by Col1,Col6 desc", 0)},
 "where Col5 is not null or Col6 is not null", 0))}
```

[image: 0]

Answer (score 0):

```
={"uniqueID", "DressTitle", "dressDescription", "dressTags", "Size", "DressImgs"; 
 ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(REGEXREPLACE({
 QUERY(SORT(IF(LEN(A2:A), {IF(ISERR(VALUE(A2:A)), A2:A, VALUE(A2:A)), 
 IF(B2:D="", A2:A&"♠", A2:A&"♦"&B2:D)}, ), 1, 1), "select *"),
 QUERY(SORT(IF(LEN(A2:A), {IF(ISERR(VALUE(A2:A)), A2:A, VALUE(A2:A)), E2:E, 
 IF(E2:E="", A2:A&"♠", A2:A&"♦"&E2:E)}, ), 1, 1, 2, 1), "select Col3"),
 QUERY(SORT(IF(LEN(A2:A), {IF(ISERR(VALUE(A2:A)), A2:A, VALUE(A2:A)), F2:F, 
 IF(F2:F="", A2:A&"♠", A2:A&"♦"&F2:F)}, ), 1, 1, 2, 1), "select Col3")},
 "(.*)♠|(.*)♦", ""), "where Col5 is not null or Col6 is not null"))}
```

[image: 0]